# Existence of the limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Good day, I'm not sure that this limit exists. All my attempts to prove it were in vain ...

Let $k>1$.
If exist, calculate the limit of the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by,
$$x_n := \Biggl(k \sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) + \frac{1}{k}\cos n \Biggr)^n.$$

Comment: Please, don't formulate your questions as if you are giving us homework. Show us what you tried and show us where you got stuck.

Comment: **Immediate required reading** (It does a body good.): [Homework-question FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: Can you find upper bounds for each term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ you have $$\sin\frac1{n^2}\le\frac1{n^2}\text{ and }\frac1k\cos n\le\frac1k,$$ so $$x_n\le\left(\frac{k}{n^2}+\frac1k\right)^n=\left(\frac{k^2+1}{kn^2}\right)^n=\left(\frac{k+\frac1k}{n^2}\right)^n.$$ (Be a little careful, though: you still have to worry about a lower bound for the $x_n$.)

Comment: tanks! I try to work ....

Comment: is correct so? :
$$ 0< \sin x < x <\tan x$$ 
if $$0 < x < \pi/2 ;$$
$$\sin \frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n^2};$$
$$-\frac{1}{k}\le\cos n \le\frac{1}{k} $$ 

then
$$x_n \le \Biggl(\frac{k^2+n^2}{kn^2}\Biggr)^n;$$
$$-{k}\le\ ksin (\frac{1}{n^2})\le{k},$$
so
$$-\Biggl(k+\frac{1}{k}\Biggr)^n\le x_n\le\Biggl(\frac{k^2+n^2}{kn^2}\Biggr)^n.$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}-\Biggl(k+\frac{1}{k}\Biggr)^n=-\infty$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\Biggl(\frac{k^2+n^2}{kn^2}\Biggr)^n=0$$
$$x_n=\nexists$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  you can replace the trig functions with the first part of their Taylor series.  How far do you have to go?

Comment: no i don't know Taylor series.

Comment: @FrConnection:  do you know that $\sin x \approx x$ for $x \ll 1$?  Similarly $\cos x \approx 1-x^2/2$ for $x \ll 1$?  If not, what tools do you have?

Comment: only significant limits and theorems on sequences